# uninitialized constant Devise::Encryptor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

It looks like I'm facing a really weird issue and it would be great if someone could help.
I have created a custom RegistrationsController which is inherited from the original devise controller. It contains only 2 methods: create and configure_sign_up_params. Also there is the following line which seems to cause the error:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```

This is done in order to allow json API calls.

So steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Restart the server
2. Make a post request to registrations#create
3. Everything works as expected
4. Change any file in the project
5. Make a post request to registrations#create
6. uninitialized constant Devise::Encryptor

If I restart the server everything will work again until I change something.

Probably the issue has nothing connected with devise itself, but any help would be appreciated.

P. S. Using WEBrick 1.3.1, ruby 2.2.1 and rails 4.2.1

Comment: paste RegistrationsController you created

Comment: Which version of devise are you using? There was a bugfix regarding Encryptor autoloading: [devise change log](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)